# Swift code executing before display updates

Tags: ios, swift

So I've just started trying out coding in swift and I'm creating an extremely basic app (purely to experiment and learn) where you click a button and two playing cards appear on the screen. 
I'm trying to get it so that when the two playing cards are the same, the button to play again disables, the program pauses for a few seconds, then the button re-enables (so later I can add some 'win' text during the pause time).

Now the button and pausing fully works besides one problem. When testing, the program pauses and then when it finishes pausing the display then updates to show the two cards being equal. But while it pauses, it shows two random non equal cards.

I'm not sure why, seeing as the cards update before I check if they're equal, but I'm new to swift (literally last few days) so not sure how it works.

Any ideas? :)

```
@IBAction func playRoundTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    // Change the card image each time the play button is pressed using a random number generator
    self.firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: String(format: "card%i", arc4random_uniform(13)+1))
    self.secondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: String(format: "card%i", arc4random_uniform(13)+1))

    // Check if the cards are equal
    if firstCardImageView.image == secondCardImageView.image && firstCardImageView.image != "card" {
        playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled=false;
        NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(4)
        playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled=true;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's more helpful to actually paste your code, rather than showing a screenshot of it.

Comment: @TimVermeulen sorry, let me change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't sleep in the main thread as this will stop all interactions with your app. You need to replace:

```
NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(4)
playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled=true;
```

with:

```
let enableTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(4 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(enableTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled=true;
}
```

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting the error "Use of unresolved identifier 'dispatch_get_main_thread'". 
Not sure if it's obvious, but I can't stress enough that I've only been using Xcode / Swift for a handful of days!

Comment: I changed it to "dispatch_get_main_queue()" and now it works like a charm, thank you very much!

Comment: @mikecbone I encourage you to also have a look at my answer, as it contains some ways in which you can improve your code.

Comment: @TimVermeulen Oh I shall be going over all the answers, I'm happily surprised at the multiple in depth replies I got, of which I'm extremely grateful for! (Wasn't sure what to expect).

Comment: @TimVermeulen I'd upvote the answers given to show my appreciation but apparently I can't do that yet, not enough rep yet! But many thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, a better solution is not pausing at all and using `dispatch_after` to change the `playRoundButton` button state after 4 seconds.

If you want to stick with pausing, then you should give time for the UI to update itself before pausing. E.g.,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_thread(), {
  //Check if both cards are equal
  if firstCardImageView.image == secondCardImageView.image && firstCardImageView.image != "card" {
      playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled=false;
      NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(4)
      playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled=true;
  }
});
```

The fact is, when you assign a new image to your buttons, the button is actually redrawn on screen only at the next run-loop cycle, so if you pause before that is run, no visual change can be seen...

Keep in mind that pausing on the main thread will make your app unresponsive during that timeframe.

Comment: You should never call `NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval` on the main queue. This will hang the whole UI and may cause your app to be terminated. (It's really rare that you should use `sleepForTimeInterval` anyway. As you say, you should use `dispatch_after`. But you should *never* use it on the main queue.)

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing two `UIImage` instances, which doesn't work with `==` because it will only compare the pointers. In your case, it would be much easier to compare the numbers that generated those images.

Other than that, you're pausing the main thread, which takes care of updating the user interface, so it doesn't actually get a chance to do so. One way to solve this problem is by using `NSTimer`.

```
@IBAction func playRoundTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    let firstNumber = arc4random_uniform(13) + 1
    let secondNumber = arc4random_uniform(13) + 1

    firstCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(firstNumber)")
    secondCardImageView.image = UIImage(named: "card\(secondNumber)")

    if firstNumber == secondNumber {
        playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled = false;
        NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(4.0, target: self, selector: "enableButton", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

func enableButton() {
    playRoundButton.userInteractionEnabled = true;
}
```

Comment: That's correct in principle, but `imageNamed` will return the same cached image when the passed name is the same... so directly comparing them works.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that. Still, I would advise against it.

Comment: @sergio are you sure that's promised? When cache memory is purged while you're suspended (which dumps the UIImage caches), I don't know if you're still promised to get the same `UIImage` wrapper back from `imageNamed:`. You might in a particular version of the OS; but I don't think this is promised. In this particular case, since it's performed back-to-back, a purge can't happen in the middle, but as a rule this would be very fragile I think.

Comment: @RobNapier: you are right, the key observation is that in the given case the two `imageNamed` are called back to back. BTW, I was not even remotely suggesting that as a good practice.